# How to pass the event object when using an inline event handler on a Stencil web component?

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs

Does anyone know how to pass the event object when using an inline event on a Stencil component?

Example:

```
  <ifx-filter-input onClick="getValues(e)">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>On2e</option>
    <option>One3</option>
  </ifx-filter-input>
```

This is my web component. I want to get the value of the selected option. How do I do that?
Passing the `e` as an argument does not work. It's `undefined`.
I tried passing `this`, but then I just get the entire component `ifx-filter-input`.

Isn't there a way to directly get the value of the selected option?

EDIT:
I have discovered that passing `event` rather than `e` works. The event object gets passed, but I still don't know how to get the selected option. The `event.target` just gives me the entire component again.

EDIT2:
Using `event.composedPath()` gives me the `<select>` element, which is inside the the `ifx-filter-input` component, but I still don't know which particular `<option>` is being clicked.

Comment: I think you can even pass nothing and reference ``event`` in your function; because ``event`` traditionally is a global, and events are processed synchronous. I would presume the value is in: ``event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].value``

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`

Comment: Removing the `value` gives you `undefined`

Comment: `event.target.selectedIndex` gives you `undefined`